# How to replace either one of the variables?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

Here's my code:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y^4
Criticalpts = Reduce[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0}, {x, y}];
Print["Critical points are ", Criticalpts]
Discr = D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] - (D[f[x, y], x, y])^2;
Print["Discriminant D(x,y) of f(x,y)= ", Discr]
```

The output of the above code is

```
Critical points are x==0||y==0
Discriminant D(x,y) of f(x,y)= -40 x^2 y^6
```

Fine till here. Now I want to calculate the value of the discriminant at critical points. (I know,  for general case evalauating the value of `D(x,y)` at infinitely many points `(x,y)` is troublesome, but for this particular function I just want to `replace x with 0 or y with 0 in -40x^2y^6` to get the output zero (similar to what I do when there is just one critical point), showing that Discriminant is zero at every critical point.)

I tried the following methods:

`Evaluate[Discr /. {x -> 0 \[Or] y -> 0}]`

`Evaluate[Discr /. Or[x -> 0, y -> 0]]`

`Evaluate[Discr /. Criticalpts`

Tried `Solve`, `Simplify` etc. Tried finding Critical pts with other methods so that I can get the value of `D(x,y)` at all the critical points directly, of course I wouldn't like to input `x==0` or `y==0` manually after seeing the output. A method which can evaluate `D(x,y)` at the critical points automatically by using an output of another command will be appreciated.

Note: I know I can first evaluate `D(x,y)` at all points on `x-axis` and then at all points on `y-axis`. Please suggest a better way to do the same.

Thank you!

Comment: In note, I meant I don't want to do this: `Evaluate[Discr /. {{x -> 0}, {y -> 0}}]` or anything similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment: If this is not what you want, let me know and I will delete my answer. At least this will help someone else provide you with the answer that you are looking for.

```
Reduce[D[f[x, y], x] == 0]
```

> `x == 0 || y == 0`

`Solve`, if successful, will give you rules directly (this will become important later), but perhaps you want to stick with `Reduce` :

```
solx = Solve[D[f[x, y], x] == 0]
```

> `{{x -> 0}, {y -> 0}}`

In order to change the OR output to rules:

```
rules = List @@ Rule @@@ Reduce[D[f[x, y], x] == 0]
```

> `{x -> 0, y -> 0}`

Remember that for complicated Boolean expressions, this strategy will fall apart. To apply rules one after the other:

```
Discr /. # & /@ rules
```

> `{0, 0}`

Comment: Use just `Discr /. {ToRules@Criticalpts} `.

Comment: I didn't know `{ }` could do this. Thanks so much. I tried List@@ etc. Can you please post an answer, and I will delete this one.

Comment: @Syed In my comment, I wrote I don't want to do this: `Evaluate[Discr /. {{x -> 0}, {y -> 0}}]` because this returns `{0,0}`. Read my note. Thank you very much for your response. I appreciate. The output which I want is just `0`.

Comment: Aman, then you need to define your function not to output `{x,y}`, but instead whatever it is that you want.

Comment: Also there's no need to delete this answer. This will help others to know that this is not what I am looking for :)

Comment: @CATrevillian I just want to show that value of discriminant for any arbitrary critical point is zero and I plan to do so by showing that "$\{x_1,y_1\}$ is a critical point" implies  "$x_1=0$  or $y_1=0$" implies "$D(x,y)$ at $\{x_1,y_1\} = -40{x_1}^2{y_1}^6=0$".

Comment: That's why I want this kind of replacement/substitution: `Discr/.{x=0 or y=0}`. My question: How can I do this using mathematica correctly @CATrevillian. Thanks, I just thought how about I do them separately (in a single line though) and get `{0,0}` as output but my final output should be `0 or 0` which is definitely `0`. Any suggestions here, Sir?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha I apply the rules using /@ : i.e., one by one: not at the same time. The `{0,0}` says that the `Discr` is zero for `x->0` and the `Discr` is zero for `y->0`. The other variable stays unchanged. Can you use a simple `If` statement on this result?

Comment: @Syed I understand what you want me to do. But this isn't what I am asking here. I am looking for a simple one line code which can give `0` as the answer. I just want to show this using mathematica:  "$x_1=0$ or $y_1=0$" implies "$D(x,y)$ at $\{x_1,y_1\}=−40{x_1}^2{y_1}^6=0$". A method which is not simple and precise is like typing the quadratic formula to find the roots of a quadratic equation in mathematica, when one is looking for Solve[eqn,var].

Comment: @Aman Kushwaha you should understand that what you want to get as an output is not impossible, but it defeats the purpose of the way that Mathematica/Wolfram Language functions to return what you see as an unfit output of the set of values held in a list surrounded by curly brackets. I suggest (& think that may be what you actually want to do) is you take the `{0,0}` that you get & post process it. You can do what you wish using something like a `ReplaceAll` to a string statement. Instead, I suggest understanding better how Mathematica works to realize what you want will need post processing.

Comment: @CATrevillian Got it. Thank you very much.