# Simplify an expression with assumptions connected with OR

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Mathematica doesn't seem to have any problem with these commands:

```
Simplify[x y, x == 0 && y == 0]
Simplify[x y, x == 0 && y == 10]
Simplify[x y, x == 1 && y == 5]
```

But when it comes to this command:

```
Simplify[x y, x == 0 \[Or] y == 0]
```

it just returns `xy` back. I know that for general cases like `Simplify[x y, x == 5 \[Or] y == -8]` there isn't any good simplification. Even so, an output like `5y||-8x` can be returned. (Please tell if there's any command to do so). But for the command `Simplify[x y, x == 0 \[Or] y == 0]`, the result is pretty obvious which is zero.

I want to know if there's any method to get the output as zero directly. Also, I don't want an output like `{0,0}` doing the substitutions alternately.

Thank You.

Comment: Previously: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256211/how-to-replace-either-one-of-the-variables

Comment: @Syed I was about to add the link here in the comments. Thanks. I'm afraid this will be marked as duplicate and will get closed, but I haven't got any helpful answer for the previous question either.

Comment: maybe something like: `ClearAll[or]; or /: Refine[a_, or[b__]] := Or @@ (Refine[a, #] & /@ {b}); Refine[x y, or[x == 5, y == -8]]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks. It does work but isn't there some inbuilt method which works just like your new modified Refine command? Also, `ClearAll[or]; or /: Refine[a_, or[b__]] := Or @@ (Refine[a, #] & /@ {b}); Refine[x y, or[x == 0, y == -0]]` returns `0||0` whereas I wanted it simplified to `0` only.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange):

```
FunctionRange[{x y, x == 0 || y == 0}, {x, y}, z]
```

> z == 0

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work on my pc. Is it not supported in Mathematica 9.0? Also, I couldn't find this in documentation centre.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha FunctionRange is new in M10.